# How to reload an entire collection in ember js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using ember and I need to update all data for a particular model.  The reload method doesn't work because it has to be an individual model.  I've looked through the docs but nowhere have I found anywhere that I can make another call to the 'index' api route and get a list of all the data back.  Does anyone know of a method to do this?

Comment: Just as a tip for future questions: if you include a JSFiddle or jsbin  which demonstrates your problem, it's much more likely that you'll get an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply do

```
App.Model.find()
```

which will load all model from server or

```
collection.forEach(function(model){
    model.reload();
}
```

which will only reload your collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `invoke` method to reload, or call any method on each item in a collection:

`collection.invoke('reload')`